# Why isn't hoarseness (dysphonia) associated with throat pain?

Tags: pain, otolaryngology, voice

Why isn't hoarseness (dysphonia) associated with throat pain?

If someone overused their vocal cords, then there is some kind of inflammation ([laryngitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laryngitis)) going on.

Common [pharyngitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharyngitis) is generally very painful, so how come hoarseness laryngitis isn't?

Comment: Why do you think laryngitis is painless? Not all hoarseness is caused by laryngitis (e.g. vocal nodules can cause painless hoarseness), but acute laryngitis is usually accompanied by significant pain.